# Unable to add SqlParameter to SqlCommand

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, ado.net

This is a strange one to me.

The signature of the `Add` parameter method requires a `SqlType` but when I use that

```
//Create and open a connection to SQL Server 
SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(DatabaseHelper.ConnectionString);
connection.Open();

//Create a Command object
SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand( "stpInsertFile", connection);
command.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;
command.Parameters.Add("@LastMod", System.Data.SqlTypes.SqlDateTime);
```

it shows this error:

> 'System.Data.SqlTypes.SqlDateTime' is a 'type', which is not valid in the given context

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be using the `SqlDbType` enumeration, not `SqlTypes` so, something like:

```
command.Parameters.Add("@LastMod", SqlDbType.DateTime);
```

Answer (score 3):

You're adding [a `SqlType`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqltypes%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) (which is just a type) but [the `Add` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wbys3e9s%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) expects [a `SqlDbType`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqldbtype%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) (which is an enum):

```
command.Parameters.Add("@LastMod", System.Data.SqlDbType.DateTime);
```

Comment: Ok thanks for the explanation. I think I was staring at the screen too long!

Answer (score 1):

The signature you're looking at is [Add(string,SqlDbType)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wbys3e9s(v=vs.110).aspx),that isn't SqlType. You're using the wrong type there. You should be using [SqlDbType](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqldbtype(v=vs.110).aspx)

Or as Christos mentioned, you can give it the value and have it figure things out.